# Gradle dependency issues while compiling

Tags: java, gradle

My ultimate aim to run the Netflix Karyon example given here
https://medium.com/@sarinduudagepala/introduction-to-netflix-karyon-266f9ae032fb

I am new to Gradle and Karyon. So before jumping into too many unknowns, I did an example using Gradle that uses a **Jackson dependency** and marshals a JSON object to file. It also **uses a custom Gradle task** to execute the application. That works perfectly fine.

**task**

```
ext {
   javaMainClass = "TestGradle.Library"
}

task runWithJavaExec(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "Execution"
    description = "Run the main class with JavaExecTask"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = javaMainClass
}
```

With this example, it is clear that that the Gradle custom task is working with external dependencies.

Now when I tried the example in the link given, I am getting errors like

```
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:3: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
                  ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:4: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
                  ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:5: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
                  ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:6: error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
                       ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:7: error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
                       ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:9: error: package com.google.inject does not exist
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
                        ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
@Singleton
 ^
  symbol: class Singleton
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
@Path("/ping")
 ^
  symbol: class Path
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        public Response getTopics() {
               ^
  symbol:   class Response
  location: class PingPongResource
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/Library.java:12: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
                                     ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:3: error: package com.netflix.governator.annotations does not exist
import com.netflix.governator.annotations.Modules;
                                         ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:6: error: package netflix.karyon does not exist
import netflix.karyon.KaryonBootstrap;
                     ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:7: error: package netflix.karyon does not exist
import netflix.karyon.ShutdownModule;
                     ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
@KaryonBootstrap(name = "pingpong-service")
 ^
  symbol: class KaryonBootstrap
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
@Modules(include = {
 ^
  symbol: class Modules
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:20: error: cannot access KaryonHttpModule
        class KaryonJerseyModuleImpl extends KaryonJerseyModule{
        ^
  class file for netflix.karyon.transport.http.KaryonHttpModule not found
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        @GET
         ^
  symbol:   class GET
  location: class PingPongResource
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         ^
  symbol:   class Produces
  location: class PingPongResource
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/PingPongResource.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                return Response.ok("{\"Response\" : \"Pong\"}").build();
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Response
  location: class PingPongResource
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/Library.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ^
  symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class Library
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/Library.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ObjectMapper
  location: class Library
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:22: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
                @Override
                ^
/Users/renjithr/WORK/LEARN/TestGradle/src/main/java/TestGradle/BootstrapInjectionModule.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        server().port(8888).threadPoolSize(100);
                        ^
  symbol:   method server()
  location: class BootstrapInjectionModule.KaryonJerseyModuleImpl
23 errors
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
    //compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    //compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.2'
    
    compile group: 'com.netflix.karyon', name: 'karyon2-admin-web', version: '2.7.1'
    compile group: 'com.netflix.karyon', name: 'karyon2-jersey-blocking', version:'2.7.1'
    compile group: 'com.netflix.karyon', name: 'karyon2-archaius', version: '2.7.1'
    
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

ext {
   //javaMainClass = "TestGradle.Library"
}

task runWithJavaExec(type: JavaExec) {
    /*group = "Execution"
    description = "Run the main class with JavaExecTask"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = javaMainClass*/
    group = "Execution"
    description = "Run Sample Ping Pong Application"

    main = "netflix.karyon.KaryonRunner"
    print  sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    jvmArgs "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
    systemProperty 'java.awt.headless', 'true'
    systemProperty 'archaius.deployment.environment', 'dev'

    args = ["TestGradle.BootstrapInjectionModule"]
}
```

**BootstrapInjectionModule.java**

```
package TestGradle;

import com.netflix.governator.annotations.Modules;

import netflix.adminresources.resources.KaryonWebAdminModule;
import netflix.karyon.KaryonBootstrap;
import netflix.karyon.ShutdownModule;
import netflix.karyon.archaius.ArchaiusBootstrap;
import netflix.karyon.jersey.blocking.KaryonJerseyModule;

@ArchaiusBootstrap
@KaryonBootstrap(name = "pingpong-service")
@Modules(include = {
        ShutdownModule.class,
        KaryonWebAdminModule.class,
        BootstrapInjectionModule.KaryonJerseyModuleImpl.class
})
public class BootstrapInjectionModule {
    
    class KaryonJerseyModuleImpl extends KaryonJerseyModule{

        @Override
        protected void configureServer() {
            server().port(8888).threadPoolSize(100);
        }
        
    }

}
```

**PingPongResource**

```
package TestGradle;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Path("/ping")
public class PingPongResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getTopics() {
        return Response.ok("{\"Response\" : \"Pong\"}").build();
    }
}
```

I wonder if it has anything to do with Karyon. Looks like some classpath issue with gradle. Kindly help.

**********UPDATE**************

posting the dependency tree in case if it helps

```
> Configure project :
file collection
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

api - API dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
\--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1 (n)

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts. (n)
No dependencies

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.2
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.2
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.2
+--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-admin-web:2.7.1
+--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-jersey-blocking:2.7.1
+--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-archaius:2.7.1
\--- com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre
     +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
     +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
     +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
     +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.8.1
     +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.2
     +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3
     \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.17

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts. (n)
No dependencies

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
\--- com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre (n)

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.2
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.2
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.2
+--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-admin-web:2.7.1
|    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.15
|    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11
|    |    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.11
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    +--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-admin:2.7.1
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11 (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1
|    |    +--- javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
|    |    +--- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.26
|    |    |    +--- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26
|    |    |    \--- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20081211
|    |    +--- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:1.9.1 -> 1.18.1
|    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:3.0
|    |    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    |    \--- org.sonatype.sisu.inject:cglib:2.2.1-v20090111
|    |    |    |         \--- asm:asm:3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:3.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.inject:guice:3.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.18.1
|    |    |         \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.1
|    |    |              \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.1
|    |    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.18.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.netflix.pytheas:pytheas-core:1.25
|    |    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    |    |    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.15
|    |    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1
|    |    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5 -> 1.6
|    |    |    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.11 -> 1.18.1
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.11
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.1
|    |    |    |    |    \--- stax:stax-api:1.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.3-1
|    |    |    |    |    \--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.2
|    |    |    |    |         +--- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2
|    |    |    |    |         \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.2 -> 1.9.11
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2 -> 1.9.11 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.2
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.2 -> 1.9.11
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2 -> 1.9.11 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:1.9.2
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.2 -> 1.9.11
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2 -> 1.9.11 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.11 -> 1.18.1
|    |    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.2
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1 -> 28.0-jre
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.8.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.17
|    |    |    +--- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:0.5.4 -> 0.6.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 28.0-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4 -> 1.7.7
|    |    |    |    +--- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.8
|    |    |    |    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    |    |    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.11
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.0
|    |    |    +--- javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
|    |    |    +--- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.8 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.11 -> 1.18.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.github.stephenc.high-scale-lib:high-scale-lib:1.1.2
|    |    |    +--- com.netflix.governator:governator:1.3.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-grapher:3.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:3.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.inject:guice:3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:3.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.inject:guice:3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.inject:guice:3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1 -> 28.0-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.xbean:xbean-finder:3.11.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.xbean:xbean-bundleutils:3.11.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.11 -> 1.7.7
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.11 -> 1.7.7
|    |    |    |    +--- asm:asm-all:3.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:3.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.3 -> 1.7.7
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.xbean:xbean-bundleutils:3.11.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:0.5.12 -> 0.6.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final
|    |    |    |         +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.6 -> 1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:1.9.1 -> 1.18.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.11 -> 1.18.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:3.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.0
|    |    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:1.4
|    |    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.1
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1
+--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-jersey-blocking:2.7.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-governator:2.7.1
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- com.netflix.governator:governator:1.3.3 (*)
|    |    \--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-core:2.7.1
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    |         \--- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:0.4.7
|    |              +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.8
|    |              \--- io.reactivex:rxnetty:0.4.7
|    |                   +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.8
|    |                   +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |    |              \--- io.netty:netty-common:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |    \--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.25.Final (*)
|    |                   |         +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.25.Final (*)
|    |                   |         \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.25.Final (*)
|    |                   +--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.0.25.Final
|    |                   |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.25.Final (*)
|    |                   |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.25.Final (*)
|    |                   \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1 -> 28.0-jre (*)
|    +--- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:0.6.3 (*)
|    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.1
|    +--- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:1.18.1 (*)
|    +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.18.1 (*)
|    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.1 (*)
+--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-archaius:2.7.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- com.netflix.karyon:karyon2-governator:2.7.1 (*)
|    \--- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:0.6.3 (*)
\--- com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre (*)
```

Comment: What versions of Gradle and Java are used? That may be relevant. I was able to compile the tutorial with Gradle 4.7 and JDK 8, which might be a clue (I don't know why).

Comment: Gradle 6 & Java 8. When i tried the "gradle dependencies" command, its compile dependencies seems to be less and does not include any of the jar files that has these classes, eve though they are available under runtime dependencies

Comment: It worked when I manually added the missing ( 2nd level )dependencies to the build.gradle. But I don't think that is the right approach. I am expecting the 1st level dependencies to resolve their dependencies at compile time. Am I doing anything wrong?...   [Note: My thought is from a Maven perspective]

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this, but sadly haven't found anything definitive and am unlikely to write it up as a proper answer. However, I summarized my notes here - https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_65019617

Comment: @MichaelEaster   Thanks... that's a lot of effort

Comment: Added dependency tree in case if it helps